# Updating object in Firebase based on a if condition

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update an object in Firebase only if one of his property doesn't exist.

The logic so far is : you loop over photos of a defined trip, and if in this photo you don't find the property "location", you update the object by inserting the property "location" (which itself is an object with properties "coord", "locationname", "regioncode", "thumbnailurl").

The problem is that after I load the page, the object "location" is not inserted for photos which don't have the property "location".

My database structure :

[image]

My JS :

```
db.ref('photos/' + owneruid + '/trips/' + tripuid).once('value').then(snap => {
    var photos = snap.val()
    for (var key in photos) {
        console.log('Photo ID is ' + key)
        var thisPhoto = photos[key]
        this.photos.push(thisPhoto)
        var hasLocation = 'location';
        if(photos[key].hasOwnProperty(hasLocation)){
            console.log("location exists")
        }
        else{
            console.log("NO LOCATION")
            var location = {coord:"", locationname:"", regioncode:"", thumbnailurl:""}
            function writeLocation(location) {
                db.ref('photos/' + owneruid + '/trips/' + tripuid + thisPhoto).update(location)
             }
             this.photos.push(thisPhoto)
             }
        }
        this.photosDataIsReady = true
})
```

As we can see in the console, the if condition in the loop works:

[image]

Comment: You haven't mentioned what problem you are facing when updating your object? is that you don't know how to update a firebase object or you are getting some kind of exception.

Comment: if it is you are unable to update the underlying object then you need to understand how firebase keeps/updates object. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data this link will help you out.

Comment: Thanks Murtaza, you are right, I didn't explain. So basically it should create the object "location" for each photo in which "location" doesn't exist, but I run the code all over again and still the object "location" is not added

Comment: Thanks for your link, but it is for admin access in java, node.js or python. Everything I'm working on now is front end with javascript. Basically when anyone loads the page, if the property "location" doesn't exist for a photo, it should create it

Comment: That's because it doesn't how it works, for the same reason I have linked an article from the firebase site in my previous comment. please go through it and give it a try. In simple words, firebase keeps records in a nosql way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
db.ref('photos/' + owneruid + '/trips/' + tripuid).once('value').then(snap => {
    var photos = snap.val()
    for (var key in photos) {
        console.log('Photo ID is ' + key)
        var thisPhoto = photos[key]
        this.photos.push(thisPhoto)
        var hasLocation = 'location';
        if(photos[key].hasOwnProperty(hasLocation)){
            console.log("location exists")
        }
        else{
            console.log("NO LOCATION")
            var location = {coord:"", locationname:"", regioncode:"", thumbnailurl:""}
                db.ref('photos/' + owneruid + '/trips/' + tripuid + thisPhoto).update(location);
             this.photos.push(thisPhoto)
             }
        }
        this.photosDataIsReady = true
})
```